# javascript searching a json object

Tags: javascript, json, search

I'm trying to search a value in json

```
<input type="text" id="test" size="21" maxlength="120">
<button onclick="Zoek()" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
        tijdelijke zoek knop
</button>
```

I'm using this to input a value and the button to call the search function

```
function Zoek() {
    var qeustion = document.getElementById("test").value;
    document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML == "";
    var text = '{ "FAQ" : [' +
        '{ "vraag":"John" , "antwoord":"Doe" },' +
        '{ "vraag":"Anna" , "antwoord":"Smith" },' +
        '{ "vraag":"Peter" , "antwoord":"Jones" } ]}';

    obj = JSON.parse(text);

    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (obj.FAQ[i].vraag == qeustion) //(obj.FAQ[i].getString("vraag").contains(question))
        {
            document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML += "<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading' role='tab' id='heading" + i + "'><h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#" + i + "' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='" + i + "''>" + obj.FAQ[i].vraag + " </a></h4></div><div id='" + i + "' class='panel-collapse collapse in' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='heading" + i + "'><div class='panel-body'> " + obj.FAQ[i].antwoord + "</div></div></div> WOWOWOWOWOWOWOWOWWOWOWOOW";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = "No results found"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my search function

so lets say i enter John it goes straigt to the else and doesnt do the if statement even though i am pretty sure it kind of is right

could anyone give me some pointers on searching in a json object? is there a other way to do this?

Comment: the answer below and jsfiddle show you what you are after. Can you confirm this works as you want? the issue is that there was no ```break``` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuenume2/) attached demonstrating what you are looking for and will show you what you need to do - https://jsfiddle.net/vuenume2/1/

It is essential to have a `break` statement in your loop.

Without the `break` statement your true value for success simply gets overwritten with false on the next iteration, except for the last possible credentials, for which there is no "next" iteration.

```
if (obj.FAQ[i].vraag == qeustion)
        {
           <!-- do stuff -->
            break;
        } else {
             <!-- do other stuff -->
        }
```

Also, if you haven't done so you need to add a div with an id `accordion` to your html

```
<div id="accordion"></div>
```

Comment: oh btw if you dont mind me asking. is there a option to do what i have but with something like contains. so like if i enter a 's' it will give me all the options with s in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter function. You parsed in obj that string into json so You could do:

```
var target = obj.FAQ.filter(function(element){ return element.vraag == qeustion})[0];
if(target == undefined) { 
  // there is no that object logic 
} else {
  // there is that object logic
}
```